# Expect is not behaving as expected when I send a command that is too long to fit on a single line

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to create an expect script which will grep a file and return the line which contains the string I am looking for, in this case the string will be a terminal ID. For example I have a file called terminal_list.txt with the following contents:

```
 0x400 192.168.62.133 10006
 0x420 192.168.62.133 10021
 0x440 192.168.62.133 10022
```

and I want the line returned which starts with 0x420

My code is as follows:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f

set terminal_list "/home/linkway/terminal_list.txt"
set termid "0x400"

spawn /bin/bash

expect "] "

    # Get ip and port of terminal
    # Check if termid exists in terminal_list file
    set command "grep -q '$termid' '$terminal_list' && echo 'true' || echo 'false'"
    send "$command\r"
    expect "$command\r\n"
    expect -re "(.*)\r\n.*] "
    set val $expect_out(1,string)
    # If terminal_list does not exist print error and exit
    if { [string first "No such file or directory" $val] >= 0 } {
      puts "$terminal_list does not exist. Script Failed"
      exit
    # If terminal_list does not contain termid print error and continue
    } elseif { [string match "false" $val] } {
      puts "\nTerminal $termid does not exist in ${terminal_list}. Cannot update bootfile.\n"
    # If termid is found in terminal_list, get the ip and port of the terminal
    } else {
      set command "grep '$termid' '$terminal_list'"
      send "$command\r"
      expect "$command\r\n"
      expect -re "(.*)\r\n.*] "
      set val $expect_out(1,string)
      set ip_port [string range $val 6 end]
    }
```

This works perfectly when I ssh to the RHEL server via putty and run the script in a maximized putty window. HOWEVER when I shrink the window length so that the grep command no longer fits on a single line my code breaks! Can anyone please help me come up with a solution to this? I have been struggling with the processing of expect_out and could really use some guidance.

EDIT: I found what was causing the bug. It turns out that when the grep command is split over multiple lines, a \r is added to the command where the line break is. Here is some debugging info from exp_internal 1. You can see how the \r is added into the grep command where the command ran onto the next line:

```
expect: does "grep -q '0x400' '/home/linkway/term \rinal_list.txt'
&& echo 'true' || echo 'false'\r\n" (spawn_id exp6)
match glob pattern "grep -q '0x400' '/home/linkway/terminal_list.txt'
&& echo 'true' || echo 'false'\r\n"? no
```

Why is this happening and what is the proper way to get just the output of the grep command? I find it very strange that expect would behave differently base on how the output of a command is displayed on screen. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does the code break? Please describe…

Comment: The reason that this code breaks is that when the grep command is sent it is split over two lines. When the command is split over multiple lines a \r is put into the buffer where the line break was. Consequently when I expect the command that was sent, expect never sees it because it does not expect a random /r to be in the command. This causes expect to timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a cleaner solution to my problem by making my script more expect-like. Here's what it looks like:

```
set command "grep -q '$termid' '$terminal_list' && echo 'true' || echo 'false'"
send "$command\r"
expect {
  -re ".*\r\ntrue\r\n.*] " {
    send "grep '$termid' '$terminal_list'\r"
    expect ".*\r\n"
    expect -re "(.*)\r\n.*] "
    set val $expect_out(1,string)
    set ip_port [string range $val 6 end]

    puts "\nUpdating $termid bootfile"
    updatebootfile $ip_port $boot_data $termid
  }
  -re ".*\r\nfalse\r\n.*] " {
    puts "\nTerminal $termid does not exist in ${terminal_list}. Cannot update bootfile.\n"
  }
  -re "No such file or directory.*] " {
    puts "$terminal_list does not exist. Script Failed"
    exit 1
  }
  timeout {
    puts "expect timeout when searching for $termid in $terminal_list"
  }
}
```